# Problem drawing angle sign without define points

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want draw this pic with TikZ:
[image]

I write this code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round]

 % First, define nodes
\node[circle, inner sep=0pt, label={[inner sep=0pt]above:{}}] (O) at (0, 0) {};
\node (O01) at (-4.5, 0) {};
\node (O11) at (-4.5, 1.1) {};
\node (O12) at (0, 1.1) {};
\node (O21) at (-4.5, -1.1) {};
\node (O22) at (0, -1.1) {};

 % Draw curved path
\draw [inner sep=0pt, line width=2pt, {Stealth[length=4mm]}-{Stealth[length=4mm]}] (O01) -- ($(O01)!2!(O)$);
\draw [inner sep=0pt, line width=2pt, {Stealth[length=4mm]}-{Stealth[length=4mm]}] (O11) -- ($(O11)!2!(O12)$);
\draw [inner sep=0pt, line width=2pt, {Stealth[length=4mm]}-{Stealth[length=4mm]}] (O21) -- ($(O21)!2!(O22)$);
\draw [inner sep=0pt, line width=2pt, -{Stealth[length=4mm]}] (O) -- (30:4.5cm);
\draw [inner sep=0pt, line width=2pt, -{Stealth[length=4mm]}] (O) -- (-50:5cm);
      
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I tried to

1. draw angle signs and text near that,
2. double arrows on straight lines,
   but I can't.

Comment: Have a look at the `tkz-euclide` package. It has options to draw angles.

Comment: You probably should define `coordinate`s instead of `node`s for that purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Use coordinates instead of nodes to name points in your diagram.
   Nodes are more useful for things that need text and have a border.
2. You can use the [`tips` key](https://tikz.dev/tikz-arrows#pgf/tips) to only draw arrow tips but no path.
3. Find the intersections between the horizontal lines and the “rays”:
4. The [`angles` library](https://tikz.dev/library-angle) is very helpful in drawing angle marks.

I've used some colors to differentiate the different parts of the diagram. Feel free to remove the color in the options.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  thick,
  >        = { Straight Barb [angle' = 60] },
  >>/.tip  = { > [sep=+0pt +-2] > },
  angle eccentricity = 1.6
]
% define coordinates where horizontal lines start and end
% draw lines and also add extra arrow tips
\foreach[count=\y from -1] \yy in {bottom, center, top}{
  \draw[<->] (0, \y) coordinate (line left \yy)
         -- +(7,  0) coordinate (line right \yy); % +(…) denotes relative coordinates
  \path[->>, tips] (line left \yy) -- +(right:1.25);
}

% define rays and draw them
% find intersection between rays and horizontal lines
\path[->, blue] (2.25, 0) coordinate (ray start)
       edge coordinate[at end] (ray down) +(-50:3)
       edge coordinate[at end] (ray up)   +( 30:4)
   (intersection of ray start--ray up   and line left    top--line right    top)
     coordinate (rayline top)
   (intersection of ray start--ray down and line left bottom--line right bottom)
     coordinate (rayline bottom);

% draw angles by defining corner and specifying angle label
% uses angles library
\foreach \Corner/\Label in {
  line right    top--rayline top--ray up/\mu_0,
  line right center--ray   start--ray up/\alpha,
  ray down--ray      start--line right center/\gamma,
  ray down--rayline bottom--line right bottom/\omega_0
} \pic[draw, green!50!black, pic text=$\Label$] {angle/.expand once=\Corner};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: When I change **\mu_0** to **\ang{30}**, get error.

Comment: @niksirat What error? Where does `\ang` comes from? This is not a macro defined by TikZ.

Answer (score 1):

Similar idea, different implementation: make your choices.

- <-> lines first, ->> lines after that (or vice versa), using relative coordinates
- using angle library, together with quotes, if you need text inserted
- using polar coordinates here and there, like `\draw[<-] (30:4) ...`
- remembering such coordinates where needed later `\draw[<-] (30:4) coordinate (A) ...`
- adjust or expand your styles within `[ ... ]`

[image: results]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,angles,quotes}

%\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[
        > = {Stealth},
    ]
    % ~~~ drawing <-> lines ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw [<->] (-4.5, 1.1) coordinate (11) -- (4.5, 1.1);
    \draw [<->] (-4.5, 0  ) coordinate (01) -- (4.5, 0  );
    \draw [<->] (-4.5,-1.1) coordinate (21) -- (4.5,-1.1);
    
    % ~~~ drawing <->> lines ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw [->>] (11) -- +(2,0);
    \draw [->>] (01) -- +(2,0);
    \draw [->>] (21) -- +(2,0);
    
    % ~~~ angles ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[<-] (30:4) coordinate (A) -- (0,0) coordinate (zero) 
        -- (0:.01) coordinate (C)
        pic[draw, <->, angle radius=16mm,"$\alpha$"] 
            {angle = C--zero--A};
            
    \draw[<-] (-40:4) coordinate (A2) -- (0,0) coordinate (zero) 
        -- (0:.01) coordinate (C)
        pic[draw, <->, angle radius=16mm,"$-40^\circ$",red] 
            {angle = A2--zero--C};
 \end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round]

 % First, define nodes
\node[circle, inner sep=0pt, label={[inner sep=0pt]above:{}}] (O) at (0, 0) {};
\node (O01) at (-4.5,    0) {01};
\node (O11) at (-4.5,  1.1) {11};
\node (O12) at (   0,  1.1) {12};
\node (O21) at (-4.5, -1.1) {21};
\node (O22) at (   0, -1.1) {22};

 % Draw curved path
\draw [inner sep=0pt, line width=2pt, 
      {Stealth[length=4mm]}-{Stealth[length=4mm]}] 
      (O01) -- ($(O01)!2!(O)$);
      
\draw [inner sep=0pt, line width=2pt, {Stealth[length=4mm]}-{Stealth[length=4mm]}] (O11) -- ($(O11)!2!(O12)$);
\draw [inner sep=0pt, line width=2pt, {Stealth[length=4mm]}-{Stealth[length=4mm]}] (O21) -- ($(O21)!2!(O22)$);
\draw [inner sep=0pt, line width=2pt, -{Stealth[length=4mm]}] (O) -- (30:4.5cm);
\draw [inner sep=0pt, line width=2pt, -{Stealth[length=4mm]}] (O) -- (-50:5cm);
      
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```